# How to update quantity of item in sessions laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes, shopping-cart

I've made a post form in the shopping-cart view where you can change the quantity of an item. This form is send to an updateCart method in the controller. It seems like the quantity is updating, but not storing it properly. I am new to laravel, so please try to keep the explanation simple:) Where Do I go wrong? I have tried the following:

```
public function updateCart(Request $request, $productnummer)
{
    $aantal = $request->input('update-aantal');
    $cart = Session::get('cart');


    if (Session::has('cart')) {
        foreach($cart->items as $item)
        {
            if ($item['item']['productnummer'] == $productnummer){
                $item['qty'] = $aantal;

                break;
            }
        }
        $request->session()->put('cart', $cart);
        Session::save();
        dd(Session::get('cart'));
    }
    return view('product.cart', ['products' => $cart->items, 'totalPrice' => $cart->totalPrice]);
}
```

**Extra information:**

Card model

```
class Cart
{
public $items = null;
public $totalQty = 0;
public $totalPrice = 0;

public function __construct($oldCart)
{
    if ($oldCart){

        $this->items = $oldCart->items;
        //dd($this->items = $oldCart->items);
        $this->totalQty = $oldCart->totalQty;
        $this->totalPrice = $oldCart->totalPrice;
    }
}

public function add($item, $id, $aantal)
{
    $storedItem = ['qty' => 0,'price' => $item->prijs, 'item' => $item];
    if ($this->items){
        if (array_key_exists($id, $this->items)) {
            $storedItem = $this->items[$id];
        }
    }
    $storedItem['qty'] += $aantal;
    $storedItem['price'] = $item->prijs * $storedItem['qty'];
    $this->items[$id] = $storedItem;
    $this->totalQty += $aantal;

    $this->totalPrice += ($item->prijs * $this->totalQty);
}
```

Route

```
Route::post('/update-cart/{productnummer}', ['uses' => 'ProductController@updateCart', 'as' => 'product.updateCart']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Session::put('cart', $cart)` instead of `$request->session()->put('cart', $cart)`. I've never used `$request->session()` before, but it looks like it is only modifying the request's session, and not the global session.

Edit: Yeah, looking at the `session()` method of the request class, it states "Get the session associated with the request" so you're not going to get that by running `Session::get('cart')` as that pulls from the global session.